# Implicit partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Say I have a function $F(P,V,T) = 0 $.
Using the chain rule: $$dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial P}dP + \frac{\partial F}{\partial V}dV + \frac{\partial F}{\partial T}dT$$ Now, if P is constant, we have $dP = 0$ and $dF = 0$ of course, because $F$ is a constant (0). We get:
$$dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial V}dV + \frac{\partial F}{\partial T}dT = 0 \implies (\frac{dV}{dT})_P = - \frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}} {\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}}$$ And that is true generally? Correct me if i'm mistaken please. Now, if we have an explicit expression for $P(T,V)$ we can also say for constant P: $$ (\frac{dV}{dT})_P = - \frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}} {\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}}$$
**BUT the results aren't always the same, why is that? Do P,V and T have to be independent of each other for the first derivation to be correct? I'm really confused and will be glad for explanation without getting too rigorous.**

**Edit:** Example (from physics):

Say:$$F(P,V,T)=PV-PNb+\frac{aN^{2}}{V}-\frac{aN^{3}b}{V^{2}}-Nk_{B}T=0$$

We can solve for P:

$$P = N\left(\frac{K_{B}T}{V-Nb}-\frac{aN}{V^{2}}\right)$$

We now get:
$$- \frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}} {\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}} \neq - \frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}} {\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}} $$

Comment: **BUT the results aren't always the same, why is that?** Examples?

Comment: I edited, thank you.

Comment: Yes it is right,  that P,V and T must be independent. This is clearly not the case at $F(P,V,T)$

Comment: But why should $- \frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}} {\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}} = - \frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}} {\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}} $ hold? I don´t see that this equation can be derived from the total differential.

Comment: If I do the same process I did with $F$ but with P that's what you get (again assuming constant $P$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer

They *are* the same, including in your example. You either did the algebra wrong or forgot one key step at the end.

## Long Answer

Yes, your thoughts are correct. If you can write $P$ as a function, then for constant $P$ satisfying $F(P,V,T)=0$, we *do* have $\dfrac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dT}=-\dfrac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}}{\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}}=-\dfrac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}}$.

### Example Case

In your particular example, $F(P,V,T)=PV-PNb+\frac{aN^{2}}{V}-\frac{aN^{3}b}{V^{2}}-Nk_{B}T=0$ we can indeed solve for $P$ to find $P=N\left(\dfrac{k_{B}T}{V-Nb}-\dfrac{aN}{V^{2}}\right)$.

Then we can calculate the two fractions. For $-\dfrac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}}{\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}}$, we get something like $\dfrac{k_B(V-Nb)V^3}{k_BTV^3-2aN(V-Nb)^2}$. But for $-\dfrac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}}$ we get something like $\dfrac{k_BNV^3}{aN^2(2Nb-V)+PV^3}$, which looks different. But we have to remember to substitute in the constant value of $P$ from $P=N\left(\dfrac{k_{B}T}{V-Nb}-\dfrac{aN}{V^{2}}\right)$. Then we get $\dfrac{k_BNV^3}{aN^2(2Nb-V)+N\left(\dfrac{k_{B}T}{V-Nb}-\dfrac{aN}{V^{2}}\right)V^3}$, which simplifies down to the same $\dfrac{k_B(V-Nb)V^3}{k_BTV^3-2aN(V-Nb)^2}$.

You can verify the calculation with Wolfram/Mathematica code:

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 458 bytes

```
Print[Simplify[Solve[P*V - P*N*b + a*N*N/V - a*N*N*N*b/(V*V) - N*kB*T == 0, P]]]
Print[Simplify[-D[N (-((kB T)/(b N - V)) - (a N)/V^2), T]/D[N (-((kB T)/(b N - V)) - (a N)/V^2), V]]]
Print[Simplify[-D[P*V - P*N*b + a*N*N/V - a*N*N*N*b/(V*V) - N*kB*T, T]/D[P*V - P*N*b + a*N*N/V - a*N*N*N*b/(V*V) - N*kB*T, V]]]
Print["Why Not the same? Substitute in for P."]
Print[Simplify[(kB N V^3)/(a N^2 (2 b N - V) + P V^3) /. P -> N (-((kB T)/(b N - V)) - (a N)/V^2)]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVBBCsIwELz7isFTEq2RelZBPIdASzyUFFJpMWit2FTo62taFEQ96GmX2Z2dmS2NO@SlcXZvuk5e7dklkS0vJ1u0SVSdbnkimUIAyQTLMIHxVfAeGboe5UQxRT0i2HHDYiyXmE8htdajt4PBNhEgASHHDWLKSQbhaYr2ZGIgKFdpSKeINf9xU31X@dfzQ/J/2ov@eHdoISoH/1DUpszXiJqsdtY1Loc9o6iukLPxh98@o4BKFz6nj5aGICGegb0POczAZ74LVvjhL1p33R0)